# Get request error using polkadotjs

Tags: pallet, json-rpc

```
let polkaAPI = require("@polkadot/api")
let key = require("@polkadot/keyring")
let Key1 = new key.Keyring( { type:'sr25519'})
let UserKey = Key1.addFromMnemonic("mneomics keys ")
let polkaProvider = new polkaAPI.WsProvider("wss://rococo-contracts-rpc.polkadot.io/" )
let PAPI = await polkaAPI.ApiPromise.create( { provider : polkaProvider } )
let nonce = await PAPI.query.system.account(UserKey.address)
let bal = await PAPI.query.balances.account(UserKey.address)
INC_CON = new PCON.ContractPromise(PAPI , inc_meta, "5DVAK9xZSEiJzWCdZGNkUjWVuXHJEgtZDgELiqYZEKwaHz2m");
let x = await 
INC_CON.query.get( UserKey.address , { gasLimit : gl  } )
x.result.toHuman()
```

When i run this code on polkadot js it give following errors

```
{ Err: { Module: { index: '40', error: '0x02000000' } } }
```

Comment: Try running the same call from polkadot apps and the error will be correctly formatted for you using [this](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/ceff524588715933585844228c6841f2e6e54076/packages/react-components/src/Status/checks.ts#L81-L95) code.

Answer (score 3):

To understand the error and get a nice message from this error when you only have the index and error, we have to take a look into the code of Substrate.

The `index` number is the index of the pallet in the runtime from which the error originated. The `error` is likewise the index of that pallet's errors which is the exact one we're looking for. Both of these indices start counting from 0.

So taking your case error `{ Err: { Module: { index: '40', error: '0x02000000' } } }` first thing we have to check is from which pallet is coming from.

In your case you are connecting to `wss://rococo-contracts-rpc.polkadot.io/` which is a Substrate parachain for smart contracts deployed on Rococo, we can see the code [here](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/parachains/runtimes/contracts/contracts-rococo).

If we check the runtime of this parachain, we find that the pallet with the [index 40](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/parachains/runtimes/contracts/contracts-rococo/src/lib.rs#L359) is the Pallet Contracts

```
// Smart Contracts.
Contracts: pallet_contracts::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>} = 40,
```

Now that we know where this error is coming from, we check the code of the [pallet Contracts](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts) to find out which is the exact one we're looking for. `0x02000000` is 2 in hex which is [OutOfGas](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L866):

```
/// The executed contract exhausted its gas limit.
    OutOfGas,
```

Answer (score 1):

I receive a the same error when running similar code with my own abi JSON. The error decodes to `contracts.OutOfGas`, which is from the [substrate contracts pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1a1600b827020cae62c9b856cb9ba4b823ab080a/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L866). Note `0x02` probably corresponds to the index of the error.

```
import { Abi, ContractPromise } from '@polkadot/api-contract'
import { ApiPromise } from '@polkadot/api'
import { Keyring } from '@polkadot/keyring'
import { WsProvider } from '@polkadot/rpc-provider'
import abiJson from 'abi.json'
import { cryptoWaitReady } from '@polkadot/util-crypto'
import { DispatchError, WeightV2 } from '@polkadot/types/interfaces'

async function getUserBalance() {
    const abi = new Abi(abiJson)
    await cryptoWaitReady()
    const Key1 = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' })
    const UserKey = Key1.addFromMnemonic(
        '...'
    )

    const polkaProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rococo-contracts-rpc.polkadot.io/')
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: polkaProvider })
    // @ts-ignore
    const maximumBlockWeight = api.consts.system.blockWeights.maxBlock as unknown as WeightV2
    const maxGas = maximumBlockWeight.refTime.toNumber() * 0.9
    // const gl = api.registry.createType('WeightV2', {
    //     refTime: maxGas,
    //     proofSize: maxGas,
    // }) as WeightV2
    const gl = 2000000000000

    const contract = new ContractPromise(api, abi, '5DVAK9xZSEiJzWCdZGNkUjWVuXHJEgtZDgELiqYZEKwaHz2m')
    const response = await contract.query.getProviderStakeDefault(UserKey.address, { gasLimit: gl })
    return response.result
}

export function getDispatchError(dispatchError: DispatchError): string {
    let message: string = dispatchError.type

    if (dispatchError.isModule) {
        try {
            const mod = dispatchError.asModule
            const error = dispatchError.registry.findMetaError(mod)

            message = `${error.section}.${error.name}`
        } catch (error) {
            // swallow
        }
    } else if (dispatchError.isToken) {
        message = `${dispatchError.type}.${dispatchError.asToken.type}`
    }

    return message
}

getUserBalance().then((x) => {
    console.log(getDispatchError(x.asErr))
    process.exit()
})
```

You can try to use the commented out code to change the gas limit into a `WeightV2` and see if that works. Is your contract deployed on the rococo contracts parachain?